# Request working properly with postman but fails with protocol error when requesting with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am trying to run this request and the reason I am doing is that from here is that I want to test push notifications (*I mean a lot of them*) with different strings in a loop.

When I try to do it with **Postman** it works perfectly fine I mean I had tried sending 300 requests and they worked fine but the request is giving an error when I am doing it with **URLSession**.

The error which I get on console is-

`error is there in data task
 The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error
2018-01-10 08:48:47.735403+0530 Universal Time Table[18533:1210462] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2018-01-10 08:48:47.735555+0530 Universal Time Table[18533:1210462] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57`

My code for sending requests is -

```
    func testNotifications(times: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    print("test notifications called")
    let url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
    urlRequest.setValue("Content-Type", forHTTPHeaderField: "application/json")
    urlRequest.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: "Key=my_API_KEY")


    do{
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: notificationJson, options: .prettyPrinted)
        urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData

    } catch let err as Error{
        print("error is", err.localizedDescription)
    }

    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("error is there in data task\n", error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error Hard Coded String")
                return
            }
            print("response is", response)
            print("Shoud be a success")
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler("responseString")
                    print("success")
                }
            }
            }.resume()
}

let notificationJson = [
    "notification":[
        "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
        "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    ],
    "data" : [
        "volume" : "3.21.15",
        "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
    ],
    "android":[
        "priority":"normal"
    ],
    "apns":[
        "headers":[
            "apns-priority":"5",
            "apns-collapse-id": "ON"
        ]
    ],
    "webpush": [
        "headers": [
            "Urgency": "high"
        ]
    ]
    ,
    "to" : "device_token"
    ] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: Can you check this lines where you are setting the HTTP header fields. The value and the fields seems to be interchanged. Print the URL request and see if it is formed correctly

Comment: Try to replace URLSession.shared with `URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
`

Comment: @user1046037, Thanks man your advice worked I by mistake inserted headers in wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headers are incorrect. You should exchange the key-value pair like this:

```
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.setValue("Key=my_API_KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Exactly that was the case I was feeling so silly when I discovered it when I was debugging it and printed the headers. 
Feeling so embarrassed.